# How to send extjs output to Yii controllers action

Tags: extjs, yii, output

i am working in extjs+ Yii. I am having my server side design in Yii and client side design in extjs. I am creating multiple choice question paper in extjs. Now on click of button i want to send questionPaperId in json format to my Yii action. So how to send extjs output to yii framework controllers action?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a post action on a standard action in a standard controller ?
It's as simple as that, just use an ajax call, and if you want to redirect them, let the ajax call give something back, and redirect with extjs.

In your controller just check for a $_POST, it works like any other action, just that it only fire upon recieving $_POST or $_GET if you wanna call the ajax by GET